# Toggling table rows inside an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have created a basic table using HTML. This table has nested elements which are supposed to open individually when you click on each assigned toggle. So when you click on a '+' icon it opens a sub menu, containing numerous table rows, each one of these has an icon 'pitch' that opens up what will be an information page when clicked on.

What is happening at the moment is that when i click '+' it only reveals the first sub-menu item, not the 2nd as well.

What I want to happen is when i click the '+' icon, it opens **ALL** the sub menu items inside and from here i can open each individual item by clicking the corresponding 'pitch' icon.

Can anyone please tell me how to amend the Javascript/HTML to make this happen?

I have attached the code below...

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 6</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1">+ </a></td>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>22/10</td>
    <td>***</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
    <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1">pitch </a></td>
    <td>List</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>22/10</td>
     <td>***</td>
    <td>23/6/2015</td>
    <td>14.95%</td>
    <td>30%</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
    <td>
        <p>HELLO</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
    <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1">pitch </a></td>
    <td>List</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>22/10</td>
     <td>***</td>
    <td>23/6/2015</td>
    <td>14.95%</td>
    <td>30%</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
    <td>
        <p>HELLO</p>
    </td>
</tr>

 <tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1">+ </a></td>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>156</td>
    <td>22/10</td>
    <td>***</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
    <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1">pitch </a></td>
    <td>List</td>
    <td>156</td>
    <td>256</td>
    <td>22/10</td>
     <td>***</td>
    <td>23/6/2015</td>
    <td>16.95%</td>
    <td>30%</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
    <td>
        <p>HELLO</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Also I have attached a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjhill44/w6dvyshj/5/) so you can see what I mean

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been struggling with this issue for some time.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggler").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
    var className = 'cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat');
    var $current= $(this).closest('tr').next();
    while($current.hasClass(className)){
        if($(this).hasClass("expand")){
           $current.show();
           $current = $current.next().next();
        }
        else{
           $current.hide();
           $current = $current.next();
        }

    }

});
    $(".pitcher").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var className = 'cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat');
    $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle();
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/w6dvyshj/8/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nextAll method instead of next:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggler").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/w6dvyshj/6/)

Comment: I am afraid this just opens up all the sub menus. When i click the '+' next to 'company 47' i want only the 2 sub menus inside it with a 'pitch' link to open (as these are related)